# Restore loki compactor data

Tags: grafana-loki

I have configured the compactor for loki and then I archive the files produced by it. I have files like `compactor.gz` and `loki-stack.gz`.

However I cannot read these files directly and I cannot find documentation on how to restore them into loki.

How can I import them into loki to exploit the archived logs ?